# Serving ASPX pages from outside the web root

Tags: asp.net

Currently working on an internationalization project.  One of the requirements is to take static files published from a content management system and serve the correct language version based on the locale.  Unfortunately the published files are .aspx and include references to master pages and potentially other controls.

If the pages are inside the web root, this is pretty easy.  I just have something in global Application_BeginRequest that takes a request for /abc.aspx and rewrites it to /content/[locale]/abc.aspx.

For ease of deployment and a couple of other reasons, I would really like these files to be outside the web root.  e.g. site is in "D:\www_root\site\" and content is in "D:\content".

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a [virtual directory](http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/planning-your-iis-architecture/understanding-sites-applications-and-virtual-directories-on-iis#Virtual) in IIS that points to `d:\content`.

> A virtual directory is a directory name (also referred to as path) that you specify in IIS and map to a physical directory on a local or remote server. The directory name then becomes part of the application's URL, and users can request the URL from a browser to access content in the physical directory, such as a Web page or a list of additional directories and files.

Comment: That works if I want the user to be redirected to /content/en/abc.aspx.  If I try to rewrite I get "The virtual path '/Content/abc.aspx' maps to another application, which is not allowed."

Comment: @Zarigani - Without more details on your setup it is not possible to tell why this error is occurring. See http://nabeeldotnet.blogspot.co.uk/2010/11/virtual-path-maps-to-another.html

Comment: Thanks Oded.  I kind of feel like an idiot now.  I'd managed to convince myself that you couldn't rewrite to a virtual directory.  Adding "~/" to the front of the rewrite path was enough to fix it.  Thanks very much for your assistance.